# Is It Possible to Create Named Destinations In A PDF Using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I'm trying to create a menu option in Adobe Acrobat that will use JavaScript to parse through a large pdf document and create named destinations using the titles in the document.

The titles all follow the same unique format, so I am able to identify them using regex.  Once I identify a title, I also identify the page it's on - and I store both the title and page number in an array.

My plan was to create the named destinations using the information stored in the array.  However, I have not had much luck figuring out how to create named destinations with JavaScript.

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this is possible...

Comment: The Acrobat JavaScript documentation refers to ISO 32000 for information about creating named destinations. Therefore, the answer to the question is "No".

Answer (score 2):

Acrobat's JavaScript API does not expose either the name tree nor the destination tree so named destinations in a document can't be created using JavaScript. For further reference [here is a link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FIntroduction_Help_TitlePage%2FAbout_This_Help.htm&rhsearch=tree) to the Acrobat's JavaScript API.

There is also a C/C++ Acrobat SDK available. It does have the ability to get the name tree and the destination tree for you. If you are willing to use a the C/C++ SDK, it might do the job for you. The API to get the name tree is

```
PDNameTree PDDocGetNameTree
```

[Here is a link](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/acrobat_pdfl_api_reference.pdf) to the C/C++ SDK documentation.